# Atualizar tabela com dados de outra tabela diminuindo caractere

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, tabela-html, sql-update

Olá, tenho o banco BDMCOM1 que tem uma tabela Saldo de Produtos e uma coluna Quantidade com valores assim: 1,000. Porém tenho outro banco BDMCOM1_V3_ALEA que tem também a tabela Saldo de Produtos e coluna Quantidade, só que com valores nesse padrão 1,00.

No caso queria saber como atualizo os valores da quantidade do banco BDMCOM1_V3_ALE com os valores do banco BDMCOM1 só que retirando um caractere para ficar no padrão correto.

Comment: Quais os tipos das colunas das duas tabelas?

Comment: Todos os dois sao decimal, porem um esta com tres casas apos a virgula e o outro 2. Porém não poso alterar a propriedade dos campos da tabela.

Comment: Se você apenas alterar normalmente o próprio mecanismo do banco já não ajeita pra você? Não retira automaticamente?

Comment: Quero pegar os dados atualizados da outra tabela e por no novo banco sem alterar sua estrutura, apenas retirando o ultimo caractere pra ficar no padrao correto.

Comment: Caso alterando normalmente e o proprio banco nao tratando isso, voce pode tentar no update ou insert arredondar o valor para duas casas como e na sua estrutura 'ROUND(VALOR, 2)'  assim ele vai formatar para duas casas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz um teste aqui:

```
declare @teste decimal(10, 3);
select @teste = 3.456;

select convert(decimal(10, 2), @teste);
-- Resultado: 3.46
```

Se os campos de origem e destino são `decimal` e precisões diferentes, a simples sobrescrita de valor funciona, mas com o prejuízo da perda da última casa decimal, com o arredondamento para cima, se a última casa estiver entre 5 e 9, e para baixo se a última casa estiver entre 0 e 4.